# How to check how many times an 'error' existed in a period of 24 hours using PHP/Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a JavaScript snippet in my page which contains ajax function in that to get the data from the database queries, The code is as follows:

```
$('#fpgo2').click(function () {
  var sanswer = $('#sanswer').val();
       if (sanswer != "") {                                                                                     
                    $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                url: root_url + '/services/services.php?method=forgotpassword',
                    data: {email:email,sanswer:sanswer},
                    async: true,
                   success: function (data) {
                    //alert(data);
                    if (data == 1) {
                                 ************
                                 ************     
                          } else if (data == 2) {
                    $('#msg_noseqqstn').html('Wrong answer').show();
                     } else {
                      alert('**********');       
                      }
                      }
                      });
                       }
                      else{
                          ***********
                          }
                          });
```

Here i want to calculate how many times the below code gets executed in a period of 24hrs

```
else if (data == 2) {
                        $('#msg_noseqqstn').html('Wrong answer').show();
                         }
```

and the condition is if I get this response for 5 times in a span of 24hrs, i'll need to do perform another function. So, can anyone let me know how can i know the number of times the error "Wrong Answer" code executed and also how to set the time period i.e, 24hrs period for the user. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good candidate for a database. You could have a table with 3 fields : `IPAddress`, `Attemps`, `LastDate` so that for each IP address you know how many attemps have been made for the current last date.

Whenever the actual date is not the same anymore, the attempt count is reseted to 1. Here is a pseudocode for what the mechanic could look like:

```
if (same date) {
    if (attemps < 5) {
        if (!try_connect()) {
            attemps++;
        }
    } else {
        error();
    }
} else { // different date
    attemps = 1;
}

lastDate = actualDate;
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: is there a way without involving database?

Comment: It is also possible to count attemps with [session vars][1] but it is all over whenever the user starts another session. This would be very easy for a bot to get around this.


[1]: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php